# Link CSR to certificate without IIS

Tags: windows, ssl, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard server and I have a CSR that I've created and I've got the GoDaddy issued cert.  But when I go to "Certificate Enrollment Requests" I don't see anything except for this key.
[image]
I've tested my CSR and my key on sslshopper, and it says they match, but I can't figure out how to tell my computer "This key matches this CSR".

Is there a way I can push my CSR into the computer (the same one that generated it) and then tell it "use this key"?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to push a **CSR** to a computer?  The CSR isn't needed once you have the issued certificate.  You need the private key, and the certificate.

Comment: @Zoredache That's what I thought, but when I import the key, it doesn't give me the "You have a private key that matches" icon and text.  It acts as if I've imported a key for which a request doesn't exist.

Comment: So did you generate the request in the same context?  IE did you generate it in the context of a user instead of local machine?

Comment: @Zoredache AHAH! No I didn't create the CSR as superuser, I created it as my regular account.  When I look at the MMC as my regular account, I see that it has the "matching private key" text.  Is there a way I can promote this key to belonging to the computer and not the personal user?

Comment: Import the cert in your regular account, and then you should be able re-export the cert with the key, and hopefully you hadn't marked the key as non-exportable.  If you can export the key+cert then you are good to import it wherever you need it.

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks.  Right now, Ive exported the key and imported it into the Local Computer account.  But it would only let me export a PFX. I have to wait before I can link it to the application.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: On the server you created this CSR, install the certificate, https://ca.godaddy.com/help/iis-8-install-a-certificate-4951 That would be enough. If you intend to also use this certificate on another machine, after installation you can export a `.pfx` file.